# Convert Excel Functions

Tags: .net, excel, statistics

I am trying to convert vba code to c#. Is there a .Net library that contain equivalant Excel functions such as `WorksheetFunction.LogInv` and `WorksheetFunction.NormDist`?

Answer (score 0):

It's in the `Application` instance. No need for extra libraries, only `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`

```
YourExcelApplication.WorksheetFunction
```